# Android Code to Get HTTP Header Info of a Web Sites

Tags: android, android-activity, get-headers

i am developing an android app wherein i need to GET HTTP headers of a website over my android activity, below cited link where i found a code but not getting all the headers.

```
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/
```

i need results like shown in the below image

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [osxdaily.com](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/get-http-header-from-website-with-curl.jpg))</sub>

please support.

Comment: what is the real issue ?

Comment: @Sreekanthss -i need to get the header detail of a website over android, as we get using this command over C#.net "foreach (string var in Request.ServerVariables) { Response.Write(var + " " + Request[var] + "<br>"); }"

Answer (score 3):

Check out the java sample code that should work with android as well:

**Method-1**

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com:80");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = conn.getHeaderFields();

Set<String> headerFieldsSet = headerFields.keySet();
Iterator<String> hearerFieldsIter = headerFieldsSet.iterator();

while (hearerFieldsIter.hasNext()) {

    String headerFieldKey = hearerFieldsIter.next();
    List<String> headerFieldValue = headerFields.get(headerFieldKey);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String value : headerFieldValue) {
        sb.append(value);
        sb.append("");
    }

    System.out.println(headerFieldKey + "=" + sb.toString());

}
```

**Method-2** (Ref: [Get headers from HttpClient in android](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/))

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://mkyong.com");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

//get all headers       
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
for (Header header : headers) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + header.getName() 
      + " ,Value : " + header.getValue());
}

//get header by 'key'
String server = response.getFirstHeader("Server").getValue();
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: thanks, but i am not getting all the headers of the website as we get using this command  over C#.net                                              "foreach (string var in Request.ServerVariables)
{
  Response.Write(var + " " + Request[var] + "<br>");
}"

Answer (score 1):

let say you have

```
HttpResponse response ;
```

then do.(for specific header)

```
Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Server");
        if (headers.length > 0) {
            String value = headers[0].getValue();
```

and to retrieve all headers

```
Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();

for(int i =0 ; i<headers.length;i++)
{
System.out.println("header : "+i+" - > "+headers[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i am not getting all the headers of the website as we get using this command over C#.net "foreach (string var in Request.ServerVariables) { Response.Write(var + " " + Request[var] + "<br>"); }" –

Answer (score 0):

Depending on http post or get you can use getAllHeaders or getHeaders method. Here is an example for http post.

HTTP POST method :

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
```

first method :

```
public Header[] getAllHeaders () 
Added in API level 1
Returns all the headers of this message. Headers are orderd in the sequence they will be sent over a connection.

Returns
all the headers of this message
```

second method description :

```
public Header[] getHeaders (String name) 
Added in API level 1
Returns all the headers with a specified name of this message. Header values are ignored. Headers are orderd in the sequence they will be sent over a connection.

Parameters
name  the name of the headers to return. 

Returns
the headers whose name property equals name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `HttpResponse` response ;   // http response
2. Get entity from  the response

   ```
   final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   if(entity == null) {
       return;
   }
   ```
3. Get the Header object from the entity. [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/Header.html)

   ```
   final Header header = entity.getContentEncoding();
   if (header == null) {
       return;
   }
   ```
4. Get each header element [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HeaderElement.html)

   ```
   for (HeaderElement h : header.getElements()) {
       if (h.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(HEADER_PARAMETER_VALUE)) {
           h.getValue();
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks, but i am not getting all the headers of the website as we get using this command over C#.net "foreach (string var in Request.ServerVariables) { Response.Write(var + " " + Request[var] + "<br>"); }"